# Xcode 7 beta 5 crashes when trying to sign Application

Tags: xcode, swift, node-webkit

I have an Application that has a helper application made with node-webkit in in. 
I can build and run the Application without problems but I cannot sign the whole Application. It seems that I am getting an error with the node-webkit application. 
The strange part is, that it works with Xcode 6.3.2.

The error I am getting is:

`2015-09-12 10:45:28 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTFoundationNSBundleAdditionsErrorDomain Code=1 "Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fc7692dd460:'/Users/proslav/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-09-12/timeBro 12.09.15 12.45.xcarchive/Products/Applications/timeBro.app/Contents/Resources/timeBroFront.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Framework.framework'>" UserInfo=0x7fc76b385380 {NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fc7692dd460:'/Users/proslav/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-09-12/timeBro 12.09.15 12.45.xcarchive/Products/Applications/timeBro.app/Contents/Resources/timeBroFront.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Framework.framework'>}
2015-09-12 10:45:28 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTFoundationNSBundleAdditionsErrorDomain Code=1 "Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fc7692dd460:'/Users/proslav/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-09-12/timeBro 12.09.15 12.45.xcarchive/Products/Applications/timeBro.app/Contents/Resources/timeBroFront.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Framework.framework'>" UserInfo=0x7fc76b385380 {NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fc7692dd460:'/Users/proslav/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-09-12/timeBro 12.09.15 12.45.xcarchive/Products/Applications/timeBro.app/Contents/Resources/timeBroFront.app/Contents/Frameworks/node-webkit Framework.framework'>}`

I don't really understand what he is missing. What does he expect me to do?

Comment: It's a beta software. 2 version have been released since. Get the GM !

Comment: So could I say the only reason is the beta?

Comment: I would say, It could be.

Comment: It might, it might not. It's beta. There are supposed to be bugs, and there is a GM, so insisting on fixing this with the beta version is daft.

Comment: Thx. I didn't realize there was a GM. Thx!

Comment: It also occurs with the gm :( any ideas?